# js function does not return when condition fulfills

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following code, I cannot find any problem out, but yet, it sometimes output 
"'i' should not be higher than handlers.length".

```
function callNext(req, res, handlers, cb) {
    let i = -1;
    let next = (thisObj) => {
        i += 1;

        if (i == handlers.length) {
            return cb();
        } else if (i > handlers.length) {
            console.log("'i' should not be higher than handlers.length.");
            console.log(handlers.length, i); // => 9 10
            return;
        }

        try {
            return handlers[i].call(thisObj || this, req, res, next);
        } catch (e) {
            this.onerror(e, req, res);
        }
    };

    return next();
}
```

Because based on human logic, the function is returned when `i` is equal to `handlers.length`, and the code below should never run, this problem really drives me nut.

Comment: if `handlers.length` is ever null, numbers greater than 1 are greater than null

Comment: @Ayon Lee is handlers sanitised to make sure, they don't call `next` twice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest assumption is that some of the handlers wrongly call `next` twice.

Generally i would recommend to safeguard again this anyways, you could use something like

```
function callNext(req, res, handlers, cb) {
   let lastCalledIndex;
   let next = (thisObj, index) => {
       if (index === lastCalledIndex) { 
           console.log("'next' called multiple times from handler");
           return; 
       }
       lastCalledIndex = index;
       if (i === handlers.length) {
           return cb();
       } else if (index > handlers.length) {
           console.log("'index' should not be higher than handlers.length.");
           console.log(handlers.length, index); // => 9 10
           return;
       }

       try {
           return handlers[index].call(thisObj || this, req, res, next.bind(undefined, thisObj, index + 1));
       } catch (e) {
           this.onerror(e, req, res);
       }
    };

    return next(this, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the enlightenment, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `i` will increment on the next call after `if (i == handlers.length) return cb();` and become `handlers.length + 1`

You  have to do

```
    if (i >= handlers.length) {
        return cb();
    }
```

or something like this.